# How do I make a span stick to the bottom of an input field with little spacing in between?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="each_new_field">
                <label class="labelified" for="whatver">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="input_classified mr_missing_field_checker" name="first_name" id="first_name">

            </div>
  <span class="field_check">First Name is required</span>
  <br />
  <div class="each_new_field">
                <label class="labelified" for="whatever2">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="a" class="input_classified">
            </div>

.input_classified {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #807C7C;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 260px;
}
.labelified {
    color: #4C5157;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 160px;
}
.field_check {
    color: #FF6600;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

With the current code, the span where it says First Name is required has space in between it and the input field above.  I need the space between them to be of 3px.  How can I move the span up naturally and then add a margin-top:3px; to it?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pFAzg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the bottom padding from the top input by doing:

```
.input_classified:first-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

and then add the margin-top to the label as you normally would:

```
.labelified {
   margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this with your html

```
<div class="each_new_field">
<label class="labelified" for="whatver">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="input_classified mr_missing_field_checker" name="first_name"  id="first_name">
      <br>
<span class="field_check">First Name is required</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a negative margin-top to push the span up, however you'd may also need to make it a block or inline block

```
.field_check {
    display: inline-block; /* don't remember if you need this, try without first */
    margin-top: -5px; /* adjust this as you need */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @populus.  This doesn't work.  With display inline block you can't have negative top margin.  And if i use display:block it still adds space in the bottom.

Comment: how about `line-height: 5px` on `.field_check`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the margins on your fields, you can try this:

```
.field_check {
    top: -10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swytg

Answer (score 0):

Set the `margin-bottom` from `.input_classified` to `0`

Comment: This works, but I'm assuming @starbucks only wants the spans to appear if form validation fails. So removing the margins will cram all the fields together when the form initially loads.

Answer (score 0):

`Position:relative`  could make it simple :)

```
   .labelified {
        color: #4C5157;
        float: left;
        font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 160px;
        position:relative;/*  ... */
        top:3px;           /* move 3 pixel down area where it's displayed */
    }
```